# CFRelease EXC_BAD_ACCESS when called with MDQueryRef

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

```
StringArray NativeSearch::search(const String &filenameglob) {

    CFStringRef queryString = jcf_getMDQueryString(filenameglob);

    MDQueryRef query;
    query = MDQueryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, queryString,
                          nullptr, nullptr);
    CFRelease(queryString);

    if (query == NULL) return StringArray();


    MDQueryExecute(query, kMDQuerySynchronous);

    int resultCount = MDQueryGetResultCount(query);
    StringArray result;

    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < resultCount; ++i) {
        const MDItemRef r = (const MDItemRef) MDQueryGetResultAtIndex(query, i);
        CFStringRef filename = (CFStringRef) MDItemCopyAttribute(r,
                                                                 CFSTR("kMDItemFSName"));
        DBG("found: " + String::fromCFString(filename));
        CFRelease(r);
        CFRelease(filename);
    }

    CFRelease(query);  // <<< EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    return result;
}
```

Any suggestions on this problem.  I was expecting to have to called *CFRelease()* on *query* as *query* was created with MDQueryCreate.  The Apple documentation suggests that's the right thing to do with a result from a Create function.

However I get a crash.  Otherwise the code works as intended.

Any thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
    CFRelease(r);
```

Is releasing an MDItem which is actually owned by the MDQuery.  This is a mistake.  It means later, when I call *CFRelease(query)* the MDItem is released for a second time.  This causes the crash.

The lessons?

- When debugging this I should have looked at every operation that could have affected my MDQuery. Instead I just focused on the operations which named the query object directly.
- Don't *CFRelease(...)* anything which you obtain through a function name called GetSomething.

To quote apple:

> Core Foundation functions have names that indicate when you own a
>   returned object:
>
> Object-creation functions that have “Create” embedded in the name;
>
> Object-duplication functions that have “Copy” embedded in the name.
>
> If
>   you own an object, it is your responsibility to relinquish ownership
>   (using CFRelease) when you have finished with it.

But: **not** when you obtain a reference to an object through a function with Get in the name!